# Две функции в самовызывающейся функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Такой вопрос

```
var bred = (function a() {
  return 1
}, function b() {
  return 2
})();
```

При вызове будет 2. Почему?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Потому что [оператор запятая](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116827/) возвращает последний операнд.
Всё равно что

```js
var bred = (1, 2);
console.log(bred);
```